# 404 error when attempting to delete tag filter

Tags: bug, tag-filters, 404-not-found

I accidentally created a new [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters); when I try to delete it, I get redirected to a 404 page, but the filter is not deleted:

[image: demonstration video]

EDIT: in 2019, it just silently fails, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328033/295232).

Comment: I don't think we could ever delete a tag filter. I don't remember ever seeing a delete link, so I have dozens of filters by now, most for testing. Guess they added a link by mistake?

Comment: @ShadowWizard they can fix it with an hover text: *For future use only*

Comment: @rene or maybe staff only, e.g. turns out they still see the old Team page. :/ (makes sense staff can delete filters.)

Comment: Can you please try this again, to see if it still 404's or if it [just silently fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328033/cant-delete-question-filters) now?

Comment: It just silently fails - no deletion.