# I can't manage to delete filters in the stackexchange.com/filters section

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, filtering

When I go into https://stackexchange.com/filters
and then click on one of them, for example, https://stackexchange.com/filters/453904/my-filter, I am shown:

The left-side allows me to edit the filter's content. on the bottom-right of that section there is a "delete this filter" link.

When I click "delete this filter", the filter still appears. I tried to either not press "Save", or press "Save", and in both cases the filter still remains present.

I may be in the exact situation of [Can't delete the filter called My Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324759/235138)?

I can't tell for sure: I may have done the same steps a few years back, and today I just went to "filtered questions" to add new tags and couldn't decide which filter was applied, so I wanted to delete them all except one.