# Deleting a network-wide filter creates a new filter in its place

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [the network filters page](https://stackexchange.com/filters/).

   - If you do not have any filters created, just create one.
2. Try to delete a filter.

   [image: Attempting to delete one of four filters. The ID is 454501 and the name is "banana".]

### Expected

One less filter.

### Actual

The same number of filters. There is a new filter named "My Filter"

[image: A new filter named "My Filter" with ID 454502 shows up in the list.]

Deleting another filter creates another new filter called "My Filter (2)":

[image: The list has a "My filter" and a "My Filter (2)" when a second filter was deleted.]

Further deletions of filters *not* named "My Filter" increment the number.

### Additional information

Deleting is done by calling `GET https://stackexchange.com/filters/delete/<filter id>` which then returns a 302 redirection to `/filters/new` which in turn creates a new filter.

Comment: "My Filter" is immortal, and raise new heads when you try to kill it, it's actually one of the oldest bugs in se.com let's find a dupe.