# Can't delete question filters; fails silently

Tags: bug, tag-filters

I use [question filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) so I can see every question asked about Clojure across the network.

Somehow though, I accidentally managed to create some empty filters:

[image]

, and I'm unable to delete them by clicking "delete this filter". If I try to delete them, the screen reloads, but the filter isn't deleted.

The odd thing is though, if I rename the filter, the renaming works. If I then try to delete it though, the name just goes back to what it was.

The only thing I can think of is somehow I created a *ton* of filters accidentally and it's only showing 4 at a time, sorted by the original name. I've tried deleting a ton though, and still haven't exhausted them if that's the case.

Note a big deal, but something seems to be bugged. Either the filters aren't being able to be deleted for some reason, or I somehow created a massive number of filters (I've never sat there and created a ton manually though, so that seems like it would be a bug, if anything).

---

To clarify, I'm not getting an error, it's just silently failing. I don't think this is a dupe unless the general consensus is just that the "delete" feature is inherently broken and particular way it's broken doesn't matter.

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't get an error though. It's just silently failing.

Comment: Yeah, let's close it the other way around.

Comment: @ Glorfindel Wait, what. I'm getting a 404 now ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Maybe they're messing with it right now. (Now it's back to failing silently).

Comment: Should be migrated to stackapps.

Comment: @smileycreations15 Why? Is the filter an app? And does Stack Apps even have a Meta site? It doesn't show one in the top-right menu.

Comment: @Carcigenicate You can discuss issues about the API there.

Comment: @smileycreations15 these are different filters than the API filters.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm not getting a 404, I see the same behaviour as you report here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't delete the filter called My Filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324759/cant-delete-the-filter-called-my-filter) though it has been bugged long before March 2019.

Comment: It looks like a long standing bug.